# Using cloned git repo instead of gem?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I'm using the Thor gem, but I have cloned the git repo to a folder and I want the system to use that one instead and not the gem, because I have added a feature in the cloned repo and want to test it.

How do I tell the system (Ubuntu 10.4) to use the cloned repo and not the installed gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to add it to the load path and then `require` it.

Either put it in a folder that is in the variable `$:` (depends on system and installation, just check in irb) or add it to that variable.

Comment: What is the difference between $: and $LOAD_PATH?

Comment: There is none, $LOAD_PATH is an alias. :)

Answer (score 0):

uninstall the previous gem, then run something like

```
$ rake build
$ gem install pkg/xxx.gem
```

or I have a plugin that automates it (commit your changes then):

```
$ gem install specific_install
$ gem specific_install -l git@github.com:rdp/win32screenshot.git # for example
```